# How to efficiently edit data in a database?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, linq

The method is supposed to receive data from a server, check if new tokens have been added, and if there are, add them to the database. If the token already exists, update its status but don't add a new row in the table. This is the code I've written so far.

```
IEnumerable<Token> serverTokens = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Token>>
(server.GetTokens().Content);
IEnumerable<Token> dbTokens = _tokenService.GetAllTokens();

foreach (var token in serverTokens)
    {
        var dbToken = dbTokens.Where(x => x.Symbol == token.Symbol).FirstOrDefault();

        if (dbToken != null)
        {
            Token editedToken = dbToken;
            editedToken.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            editedToken.Active = token.Active;
            _tokenService.AddToken(editedToken);
        }
        else
        {
            token.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            _tokenService.AddToken(token);
        }
    }
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The `AddToken` method is just a simple `AddOrUpdate` operation.

```
public void AddToken(Token token)
        {
            _dbContext.Tokens.AddOrUpdate(token);
            //_dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Now, this code does what it's supposed to, however it's extremely slow. How would I go about optimizing it?

Comment: Is this ef core?

Comment: Is _tokenService external service (e.g calling db or api to get this tokens) ?

Comment: @Silvermind just ef 6

Comment: If you are using EF. There is no need to do AddOrUpdate in case if entity already in DB SaveChanges enough

Comment: @Dimitar _tokenService calls a db, server calls an api

Comment: In that case one possible bottleneck is to wait for this IO operation (adding token). Consider making adding tokens method asynchronously if possible or on bulk.

Comment: Bluck inset in temp table and merge?

Comment: What does the method GetAllTokens look like?  Are you materializing all tokens from your DB?  That could definitely be a performance killer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dbTokens.Where(x => x.Symbol == token.Symbol) is IEnumerable

So he will load it each time you call it on the loop.
Store in in a list before the loop

```
List<Token> dbTokens = _tokenService.GetAllTokens().ToList()
```

Comment: Still just as slow, I measured it.

Comment: What is the size of the table in db? how much token to update or create are send by the servers? According to this maybe all the token wont need to be load in the application.

Comment: 270 rows of data, and approximately the same rows returned by the server

Comment: can you use sql profiler to show the generated sql query? also how slow is "slow"? a simple db insert on a small table should be pretty darn quick. Is this being ran locally where the db is on the same machine as the code that is running?

Comment: Can you monitor your code (instrumentation) to identify the function or call who is slow ? would help.